# One word or a phrase other than those given to describe testing how a person reacts to a test move

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I am looking for a generic word/term for an act which is done to test the response of the opponent. In other words, how a person reacts to a move, before the final act is executed.

Let me elucidate it with examples:

> Let's suppose an Article *xyz* in the consitution has 3 major clauses and one very minor adjunct. The Government wants to repeal it in entirety. So, it first tampers with that minor adjunct to see the response of the opposition and the honorable courts to it, before it chooses to repeal the entire Article *xyz* all together.

This tampering was a ***trial balloon*** by the government to see how opposition reacts to it.

Another example from events prior to World War 2:

> On 7 March 1936 German troops re-occupied the Rhineland, a de-militarised zone according to the Treaty of Versailles. This action was directly against the terms which Germany had accepted after the First World War.

Historians of different hues believe that this was done to test the response of Britain and France. So, one would say that this was a ***test case*** for Hitler, before he decided to launch his bigger plans.

In both the cases, a *bait* or a *decoy* was put to test a proposition. These two examples were like *Guinea Pigs* to test how the other side reacts.

I am looking for a generic word for ***trial balloon*** and ***test case*** - something done to test the instincts of the opponent.

Comment: Feint, a deceptive or pretended blow, thrust, or other movement, especially in boxing or fencing.
"a brief feint at the opponent's face"

Comment: Well, I suppose it means a diverting move. Here one's intention is to not divert the focus of the opponent, but to see how the opponent reacts, before one launches full assault. Diversion or no diversion is besides the point.

Comment: I don't understand the distinction you're making.

Comment: What I am trying to say is, instead of taking complete action, one takes a small action to get an idea as to how the opponent will react, before going full throttle. Equovocating, diversions etc to cause confusion can be an instrument to an end, but the end is to understand how the opponent reacts, rather win/loss.

Comment: Trial balloon applies to both examples. Neither uses a decoy or diversion, but goes straight to a small test element.

Comment: @YosefBaskin I agree, trial balloon conveys the meaning. But, I would use something which is more common in the literature.

Comment: *Let's see if they take the **bait**.*

Comment: *running interference* is to make sure whatever we want to do will work. "On 7 March 1936 German troops" *ran interference* in the Rhineland, for the prospect of invading Poland.

Comment: *trial balloon* hurts my brain. Someone [Run it up the flagpole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run_it_up_the_flagpole)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Perhaps the most common way to express this is to use the metaphor **testing the water**.

> *test the water* [phrase of *test*]
>
> judge people's feelings or opinions before taking further action.

[[Oxford Languages; courtesy of Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22test+the+water%22+meaning&rlz=1C1CHBF_en-GBGB973GB973&oq=%22test+the+water%22+meaning&aqs=chrome..69i57j0i512j0i10i512l2j0i22i30j0i15i22i30l4j0i22i30.508032105j0j15&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)]

'... before taking *further* action' can be paraphrased '... before *fully* committing'.

> *test the water(s)*
>
> To informally or casually attempt to gauge the reaction of a potential
> audience or recipient of something, or to try to get an idea of what
> something will be like before actually doing it. Likened to feeling
> the temperature of water before getting in.
>
> - I want to test the water before I make the proposal at the general meeting. Do you think you can float the idea to the boss and gauge his
>   reaction?
> - You better test the waters before you fully commit to that plan.

[[Farlex Dictionary of Idioms. © 2022](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/test+the+waters)]

Comment: Very apt. This is what I was looking for. Let me see if someone comes with something else. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You can also ***feel [things] out*** or ***float** [an idea, proposal].* Or try something out to ***see if it flies***.

Comment: That makes sense as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The following sense of "poke" allows an expression that can possibly apply in certain contexts;  "*poke the bear*" is that expression; it seems, however that it is not used a lot.

> (**SOED**) **5**. Make, produce, find *out* or stir *up* by poking.

- ([Power and Protest at an American University: No Confidence, ...
  Ellen Carnaghan, ‎Kathryn E. Kuhn · 2020](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Power_and_Protest_at_an_American_Univers/kKb8DwAAQBAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22poke+the%22&pg=PT77&printsec=frontcover)) Having observed the tactics of the administration, and of the president, the rebel alliance turned to a classic insurgent strategy that eventually succeeded beyond our wildest hopes: Poke The Bear. The reasoning was as follows:
- ([The Complete Idiot's Guide to Persuasion: Win People Over ...
  Steve Booth-Butterfield, Ed.D. · 2009](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/The_Complete_Idiot_s_Guide_to_Persuasion/9y168y26bIQC?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22poke+the+bear%22&pg=PT47&printsec=frontcover)) Now, you're hoping that you poke the bear the proper way and that things work out positively for you—but if you're wrong, you don't have the status quo anymore. Things don't remain the same as they were before you poked the bear.
- ([I'm from Bouctouche, Me: Roots Matter
  Donald J. Savoie · 2009](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/I_m_from_Bouctouche_Me/LYJpDtJdDRAC?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22poke+the+bear%22&pg=PT137&printsec=frontcover)) Québécois and Acadians from northern New Brunswick, meanwhile, had had a vastly different conditioning. They would not hesitate to poke the bear, and what they saw in Moncton gave them every reason to poke it and poke it hard.
- ([Strategic Weapons Proposals: Hearings Before the Committee ...
  United States. Congress. Senate. Committee on Foreign Relations · 1981](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Strategic_Weapons_Proposals/TrZJAQAAIAAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22poke+the+bear%22&pg=RA1-PA41&printsec=frontcover)) This is not all within your bailiwick , but it appears as thoughand maybe I am being partisan - it appears as though in this administration thus far we have tended to poke the bear because that was part of the policy

Comment: That was new for me, but makes complete sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Sticking to nouns I suggest either **provocation** or **gambit**.

My dictionary (Chambers 11th edn) defines *provoke*, from which *provocation* is derived, as

> to annoy or exasperate; to excite or to call into action, stimulate;
> to incite or bring about; ...

It also provides

> to call out or to challenge

but suggests that this meaning is obsolete.

As for *gambit*

> in chess, the (offer of a) sacrifice of a piece for the sake of an
> advantage in timing or position in the opening stages of a game ...; an
> initial move in any strategy or battle of wits, *esp* one with an
> element of trickery

Provocations are often hostile, as the occupation of the Rhineland was, and the same event might have turned into a sacrifice had the UK and France responded with force.

Comment: Provocation would mean goading or actuating someone into action, but for me even inaction is fine. I just want to see the natural response, irrespective of what it may be.

Comment: To my reading *provocations* may well be intended to goad, but they won't always do so.